# how to parse page numbers using Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

```
<?php 
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'table');
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}

include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$startpage=2;
$endpage=8;
for($i=$startpage;$i<=$endpage;$i++){
$html = file_get_html("http://some site.com/page=$i");
}

foreach($html->find("div.tt-name") as $title2)
{
$title[]=  $mysqli->real_escape_string(trim($title2->plaintext));
echo $title2->plaintext.'<br>';
}

?>
```

i want to parse page numbers like from page=2 to page=8 i want to fetch data from all these pages like, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8 but right now its only showing page=8.. what am i missing?

Comment: Your `for($i=$startpage;$i<=$endpage;$i++)` block is closed too early

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing is the wrong word here, but lets ignore that. Your problem is that you don't understand the concept of a loop.

Run this code:

```
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
{
   $y = $i;
}
echo $y . '<br/>';
```

You'll notice that the only value to be printed is 9.  Why?  Because each iteration of the loop overwrites the value in the variable.

If you want to do something with each value rather than only the last value, then put the code that uses the value ***inside*** the loop:

```
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
{
   $y = $i;
   echo $y . '<br/>';
}
```

Thus, for your code:

```
for($i=$startpage;$i<=$endpage;$i++)
{
  $html = file_get_html("http://some site.com/page=$i");
  foreach($html->find("div.tt-name") as $title2)
  {
    $title[]=  $mysqli->real_escape_string(trim($title2->plaintext));
    echo $title2->plaintext.'<br>';
  }
}
```

Comment: ok thanks alot @developerwjk ..can you tell me how to go inside the each link from the page numbers.. eg: every page has 20 posts and every post has 2 divs and i want to fetch these 2 divs also